# Is it possible to call a robot method outside of "main" robot class?

Tags: java, robocode

I'm trying to make a robot in the robocode environment. My question is, if I want (for example) to call the method "fire()" outside of my robot class (so the class that extends Robot and has the run, onHitBybullet, ... methods), how do I do it?

This is just one of the things I tried (my latest):

```
package sample;

import robocode.HitByBulletEvent;
import robocode.Robot;
import robocode.ScannedRobotEvent;
import sample.Interpretater;

public class MyFirstRobot extends Robot {

Interpretater inter;

public void run() {
    intel = new Interpretator();
    while (true) {
        ahead(50); // Move ahead 100
        //turnGunRight(360); // Spin gun around
        back(50); // Move back 100
        //turnGunRight(360); // Spin gun around
    }
}

public void onScannedRobot(ScannedRobotEvent e) {
    /*If I write fire() here, it will work, but I want to call it 
    from some other class (intel)*/
    inter.onScan();
}

public void onHitByBullet(HitByBulletEvent e) {
    turnLeft(90 - e.getBearing());
}
}
```

Interpreter code :

package sample;

```
public class Interpretator extends MyFirstRobot
{
public Interpretator(){

}

public void onScan(){
    fire(1); //won't work, throws "you cannot call fire() before run()"
}
}
```

I'm not an expert in java at all, so maybe I'm missing something, but I tried creating another class and making it extend my robot class (therefore inheriting the Robot methods) but then java threw errors since a class that extends Robot needs the run, onHitByBullet .. methods.

Comment: Please show relevant  code and errors, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like a design problem.

Your solution works, but when you add more methods than onScan, you will need to pass `this` to every call you make from MyFirstRobot

Instead, pass a reference to `this` in Interpretater's constructor.

Your error happens because Interpretator extends MyFirstRobot. When you call `fire(1)` without the robot reference, it calls it on Interpretator, which hasn't run `run()` yet. It looks like you're only using Interpretator as a reference to make decisions based on the robot, so Interpretator is not a Robot.

Making these changes (along with formatting) gets:

```
package sample;

import robocode.HitByBulletEvent;
import robocode.Robot;
import robocode.ScannedRobotEvent;
import sample.Interpretater;

public class MyFirstRobot extends Robot {

    Interpretater inter;

    public void run() {
        inter = new Interpretator(this); // intel looked like a typo
        while (true) {
            ahead(50); // Move ahead 100
            // turnGunRight(360); // Spin gun around
            back(50); // Move back 100
            // turnGunRight(360); // Spin gun around
        }
    }

    public void onScannedRobot(ScannedRobotEvent e) {
        /*
         * If I write fire() here, it will work, but I want to call it from some
         * other class (intel)
         */
        inter.onScan();
    }

    public void onHitByBullet(HitByBulletEvent e) {
        turnLeft(90 - e.getBearing());
    }
}
```

and

```
public class Interpretator {

    MyFirstRobot robot;

    public Interpretator(MyFirstRobot robot_arg) {
        // constructor sets instance variable
        robot = robot_arg;
    }

    public void onScan() {
        robot.fire(1); // use reference
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A possible answer I have found is to modify Intepreter.onScan() such that it looks like

```
public class Interpretator extends MyFirstRobot
{
public Interpretator(){

}

    public void onScan(MyFirstRobot robot){
        robot.fire(1); 
    }
}
```

And in the onScannedRobot simply put as parameter *this*.

Do give a better answer if you have one.